# Is there a way of seeing if user input matches variable name in c++?

Tags: c++, variables, concurrency, io, uci

I am writing a program in C++ where there are some variables i want to tune using a genetic algorithm, but finding the fitness value for a single chromosome is relatively slow.

Therefore i want to use concurrency when computing the fitness values of all individuals, but the only way to do this is by using several compiled programs and i want to be able to specify the variables at runtime through the command line (commands are given from a kind of "master" program with a UCI-like protocol), but i dont know any ways to check if there exists a variable with the same name as an input string from cmd.

My question is therefore: Is it even possible to check if a command line input matches a variable name in c++?

Comment: Once compiled the variable names from the code no longer exist.

Comment: It is possible if you write the code to do it. Although from a more practical viewpoint, this would basically be normal command line processing -- check if the input matches a given string and do something with it. As an example/explanation: `if ( input_name == "factor" ) factor = input_value;` -- note that in this example, there is no intrinsic reason the string and variable name have to be the same, other than that is what you requested.

Comment: If you have, say, a variable named "grommit", can you explain what difficulty you have with implementing code that simply checks if the word that was read was "grommit"?

Comment: @JaMiT's solution works if you just have a few such variables.  But if you have many, then you might be better off storing the values in a _hash table_ instead of storing the values in variables.

Comment: There are command line parsing libraries that can help you with this. One such is: [https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11](https://github.com/CLIUtils/CLI11)